# No puedo configurar Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Tengo el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate persister: org.hibernate.tutorial.annotations.Persona.

Estuve mirando la documentación pero no encuentro forma de resolverlo y me cuesta orientarme en la misma. Estoy usando la última versión de Hibernate 6.0.0.Final la cual me está dando algunos dolores de cabeza. Tuve que reemplazar el método `.save()` por `.persistence()` porque el primero quedó obsoleto y también cambiar la forma en que inicializo Hibernate. Al ser principiante desconozco si en estos cambios que hice leyendo la documentación cometí algún error.

Clase principal:

```
package org.hibernate.tutorial.annotations;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;





public class AnnotationsIllustrationTest  {
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    

         SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        // A SessionFactory is set up once for an application!
        final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml  
                .build();
        
            sessionFactory = new MetadataSources( registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        
        

            
            try {
                
                Persona persona1 = new Persona ("a","b","c",54);
                
                session.beginTransaction();
                
                session.persist(persona1);
                
                session.getTransaction().commit();
                
                System.out.println("registro insertado");
                    
                }   finally {
                        
                    sessionFactory.close();
                
                    }
            }
}
```

Entidad

```
package org.hibernate.tutorial.annotations;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Table;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity (name ="persona")
@Table(appliesTo = "persona" )
public class Persona {

@Id
@Column(name = "id_persona")
int id;
@Column(name = "nombre")
String  nombre;
@Column(name = "apellido")
String  apellido;
@Column(name = "mail")
String  mail;
@Column(name = "telefono")
int telefono;



public Persona(String nombre, String apellido, String mail, int telefono) {
    super();
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.mail = mail;
    this.telefono = telefono;
}




public Persona() {
    
}




public int getId() {
    return id;
}




public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}




public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}




public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}




public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}




public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}




public String getMail() {
    return mail;
}




public void setMail(String mail) {
    this.mail = mail;
}




public int getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}




public void setTelefono(int telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}




@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Persona [id=" + id + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", apellido=" + apellido + ", mail=" + mail + ", telefono="
            + telefono + "]";
}
    
}
```

Configuración

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
  <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
      <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</property>
      <property name="connection.username">root</property>
      <property name="connection.password">admin</property>
      <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

   </session-factory>
 </hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la metadata te falto mappear las entidades que quieres meter a hibernate.

deberia quedarte algo como...

```java
...
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final StandartServiceRegistry registry = new StandartServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .configure()
            .build();

        //Aqui construyes el metadata, aqui es donde registras las clases.
        Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(registry)
            .addAnnotatedClass(Persona.class) //Esto es lo que registra o mapea la clase, ojo, esto toma en cuenta las annotaciones de hibernate que has puesto en el pojo, para mas info mirate el javadoc de MetadataSources.
            .buildMetadata();

        //Ahora si, el session factory.

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = metadata.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
...
```

> **Referencias.**
>
> - *Tutorial del uso de metadata - Hibernate User Guide* https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-native-metadata
> - *MetadataSources - Javadoc* https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/MetadataSources.html
> - *Metadata - Javadoc* https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/Metadata.html

Comment: muchísimas gracias, funcionó. no entiendo por qué en el ejemplo oficial del tutorial oficial de Hibernate no está esa línea. (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/quickstart/html_single/#tutorial_annotations)

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que decirle a Hibernate cuáles son las clases Entidades:

```
List<Class<?>> classes = EntityScanner
        .scanPackages("org.hibernate.tutorial.annotations").result();

MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources(registry);
for (Class<?> annotatedClass : classes) {
    metadataSources.addAnnotatedClass(annotatedClass);
}
sessionFactory = metadataSources.buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
```

Para esto necesitas usar la librería [`fluent-hibernate`](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate)

Comment: tenes idea como hacerlo sin spring?

Comment: no me deja acceder a ese método de EntityScanner.  agregué la dependencia autoconfigure de spring boot pero no es una clase estática asi que tengo que crearla con el applicationContext pero no tengo eso en mi app ni lo quiero tener la verdad. Debería haber un método más fácil.

Comment: Déjame echar un vistazo

Comment: me tira otro error que googlie y no pude solucionar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Entity
 at com.github.fluent.hibernate.cfg.scanner.EntityScanner.scanPackages(EntityScanner.java:52).  (la linea 52 es la que tiene List<Class<?>> classes = EntityScanner.scanPackages("org.hibernate.tutorial.annotations").result();

De cualquier manera no debería ser necesario tener que importar fluent-hibernate para configurarlo correctamente.

Comment: Puedes definir todo usando un xml

Comment: muchas gracias al final no apliqué tu solución pero aunque me de error (mas adelante veré como lo soluciono. Por ahora no necesito)  me parece una manera muy útil de simplificar el código y es bueno conocerla.